# django how to populate a drop down list with two values from the same row in a database

Tags: python, django

I am trying to populate a drop down list in django with two values from the same row.

expected output

```
 Product category - product name
```

actual output

```
 product name
```

forms.py

```
class AddproductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = product
        fields = [
        'category','name']
```

products.html

```
{{ form.category.form.name}}
```

Comment: Why do you expect that to output two values when you only show one?

Comment: because I have included two form values as show in products.html

Comment: Please share more code, your `Product` model and products.html.